# jquery dialog's input fields freezes in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-dialog

I have some jquery dialogs added in my application where in one scenario I open up a 1st dialog and upon entries into some field I am prompted with a message containing some server side messages and that prompt is again a 2nd jquery dialog. that means i have 2 dialogs opened over each other. so when i click on the top most(2nd) dialog then both the dialogs' `$('#div1').dialog('close')` and `$('#div2').dialog('close')` are called I am redirected to another page. Now here is what the issue arises, I am on new page with both dialogs closed, now if I open up the 1st dialog again it opens up but with everything frozen. I mean it literally takes no input but a cursor keeps blinking in first field. This happens only in Firefox, in Chrome it works like a charm.